# Assisted Attributions into Silverpop

Tags: javascript, tags, tagging

Has anyone worked with Silverpop (IBM)?  I am trying to get our view-through conversions such as a display banner or YouTube videos to sync into the Silverpop database system so we can see if they result in a sale.

Currently, we are only getting clicked through conversions from paid search.  Does anyone know what needs to be included in the Javascript in order to see the view through conversions and also all touchpoints in the journey?

Not sure if it is another cookie value or some type of tracking script.  The website is coded in JavaScript.